# Connect Multiple MySQL Databases Running on Different Servers

Tags: mysql, database, database-connection

I went through different SO links. But, not found my answer. This link

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/118488/interacting-with-data-using-multiple-databases-servers

helped me.

But, still I am yet to get my answer.

I am trying to connect multiple databases running on different servers. I am using PHP. But, it is showing warning

> Warning: mysql_connect(): Host 'User-PC' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

For testing purpose, I am trying this on LAN. I am running MySQL server on machine with IP 192.168.1.7. And, I am trying to connect it from machine with IP 192.168.1.8.

Answer (score 0):

The user you are trying to connect from is probably not allowed to connect to a MySQL server from the given IP of the machine.
Try to grant access with the following command:
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'192.168.1.8' WITH GRANT OPTION;`


Don't forget to flush the newly added privileges before testing:
`FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`